# Lack of memory implies exponential

Tags: probability

I'm seeing the post [Hints lack of memory implies exponential distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3034166/hints-lack-of-memory-implies-exponential-distributiom) and the answers. I'm wondering about the second answer. The argument there is that the only non-zero function that has the property $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ is the exponential?

Thanks

Comment: You should add some extra hypothesis, such as continuity (or many other options). See [Cauchy's functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation).

Comment: Continuing @WhatsUp's line of thought: in this case it's almost everywhere continuity. 1 minus the cdf is the function that satisfies the given functional equation. And this function is almost everywhere continuous, which is sufficient to make the exponential functions the only class of functions satisfying the equation.

Comment: I've just edited the question since it was slightly wrong. I wrote $f(x)+f(y)$ when it should be $f(x)f(y)$. I think that the Cauchy's functional equation does not apply in this case, am I correct?

Comment: Do you know $\log$ and $\exp$ functions? They make $f(x)f(y)$ not much different from $f(x) + f(y)$.

Comment: I know both. Is it relevant that to the question? I need it to be exactly $f(x)f(y)$ and not just similar. Thanks for the answers